# Model summary and diagnostics for instrumental variables in R

Tags: r, stargazer, modelsummary, ivreg

I run instrumental variable regression (2SLS) with `ivreg` package.

```
library(ivreg)
as_tibble(mtcars)

model_iv <- ivreg(formula = mpg ~ disp + drat |
                                         drat + carb,
              data = mtcars)
```

As many other people, I am interested in the diagnostics (e.g. weak instruments, wu-hausman and sargan) attached to my model reporting.

```
summary(model_iv, diagnostics = TRUE)

Diagnostic tests:
                 df1 df2 statistic p-value   
Weak instruments   1  29     8.286 0.00743 **
Wu-Hausman         1  28    11.594 0.00202 **
Sargan             0  NA        NA      NA   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

There is a workaround to add those to `stargazer`:

[R: Robust SE's and model diagnostics in stargazer table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048097/r-robust-ses-and-model-diagnostics-in-stargazer-table)

And I found the very discussion in an issue for `modelsummary`:

https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues/123

I tried the `modelsummary` but it seems that the feature hasn't been implemented. Is there another package for model reporting including diagnostics for instrumental variable models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with `modelsummary`. Please see the detailed documentation on how to add new goodness-of-fit statistics on the website: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#new-models-and-custom-statistics

There are basically 3 options.

#### Option 1: `add_rows`

Build your own data frame with the same number of columns as your table, and use the `add_rows` argument to stick it at the bottom of the table. This allows you full control, but can be tedious. It is also quite self-explanatory, so I don’t give an example here. Just see `?modelsummary`.

#### Option 2: `metrics` argument

Behind the scenes, `modelsummary` extracts goodness of fit statistics using the `performance` package. That package supports a `metrics="all"` argument which sometimes return more information. In this case, we can feed `metrics` directly to `modelsummary` and get the Wu-Haussman statistic:

```r
library(ivreg)
library(tibble)
library(modelsummary)

model_iv <- ivreg(
    formula = mpg ~ disp + drat | drat + carb,
    data = mtcars)

modelsummary(model_iv, metrics = "all")
```

|  | (1) |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 51.687 |
|  | (17.451) |
| disp | -0.072 |
|  | (0.020) |
| drat | -4.169 |
|  | (3.649) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |
| R2 | 0.455 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.418 |
| AIC | 193.3 |
| BIC | 199.2 |
| RMSE | 4.38 |
| wu.hausman | 11.5944242731131 |
| wu.hausman.p | 0.00201604586133519 |

Of course, you’ll probably want to format this statistic with the `gof_map` argument to reduce the number of digits and clean up the names.

#### Option 3: `glance_custom`

Finally, you can define a `glance_custom.ivreg()` method to extract, format, and add the statistic automatically. There is a detailed tutorial at the link I posted above, so here’s a simple example:

```r
glance_custom.ivreg <- function(x, ...) { # don't forget ...
    s <- summary(x)$diagnostics
    wi <- s[1, "statistic"]
    wh <- s[2, "statistic"]
    tibble(
        "Weak Instrument" = round(wi, 2),
        "Wu-Haussman" = round(wh, 3))
}

modelsummary(model_iv)
```

|  | (1) |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 51.687 |
|  | (17.451) |
| disp | -0.072 |
|  | (0.020) |
| drat | -4.169 |
|  | (3.649) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |
| R2 | 0.455 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.418 |
| AIC | 193.3 |
| BIC | 199.2 |
| RMSE | 4.38 |
| Weak Instrument | 8.29 |
| Wu-Haussman | 11.594 |

All subsequent `ivreg` models will automatically have this new statistic.