# modelsummary to display deviance explained

Tags: r, gam, modelsummary

I am running a Generalized Additive Model from the `mgcv` package

I would like to display the `deviance explained` in the table instead of just the R-squared with the `modelsummary` package, how can I accomplish this?

```
modelsummary(models,
             estimate = "estimate",
             stars = TRUE,              
             statistic = c("Std.Error" = "std.error", 
                           "t-value" = "statistic"))
```

Comment: The `modelsummary` website includes a very detailed vignette explaining how one can include additional goodness-of-fit statistics: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#new-models-and-custom-statistics

Comment: Also see this near duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75545942/model-summary-and-diagnostics-for-instrumental-variables-in-r